# Telegram bot : SendPhoto method doesn't work

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have a bot and this bot send some message to my channel with a cronjob. these messages are kind of photo, simple text, video, gif(document) and voice.
some time's I try to send photos with below code:

```
            $this->api->apiRequest(
                'sendPhoto',
                array(
                    'chat_id' => $this->chatid,
                    'photo' => $this->msg_data['file_id'],
                    'caption' => $this->msg_text,
                    'reply_to_message_id' => $this->message_id,
                    'reply_markup' => $reply_markup,
                )
            );
```

What is the problem? Why does not send some photos?

I got this error from telegram API

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question is incomplete. It doesn't provide an error message or at least a hint of what could go wrong and where. We don't posses magic balls to guestimate the error.

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: @Andrew i add the error

Comment: @Sean the error attached

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$this->msg_data['file_id']`?

Comment: What did you receive? e.g., Voice message

Comment: @ceejayoz , I receive my file id from callbaqck_query with this code : $this->msg_data['file_id'] = (is_array($this->msg->message->photo)) ? $this->msg->message->photo[0]->file_id : $this->msg->message->photo->file_id;

Comment: @Sean | $this->msg_data['file_id'] = (is_array($this->msg->message->photo)) ? $this->msg->message->photo[0]->file_id : $this->msg->message->photo->file_id;

Comment: And what about `getFile` with same File ID

Comment: I'm not asking how you construct `$this->msg_data['file_id']`. I'm asking if you've printed/logged out its value and made sure it's *correct*.

Comment: @ceejayoz the file id was true but doesn't have file size and I understand how solve this problem , Thank you ♥

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved! the file_id I send it to api is wrong and I should set a file id when have file size !